# Java Quoting string variables

Tags: java, string, escaping, quotes

I want this to be printed out

> ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars "host=5.955.595 user=root
>   pass=anotherpw vm=myVm"

This is my code. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
    String ip = "5.595.595";
    String usr = "root";
    String pw = "anotherpw";
    String vmName = "myVm";

    String p = "ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host\"= '"+ip+"' \"user\"='"+usr+"' \"pass\"= '"+pw+"'  \"vm\"= '"+vmName+"' " ";
    System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error? Does it print something else instead?

Comment: you want *"host=5* so why do *st\"=* no end quote required. and what are single quotes for?

Comment: May I suggest a way way to make it easier on yourself: look at `String.format(...)` and/or `StringBuilder` to assemble long Strings like this.

Comment: suppose you have additional quote in the end. `String p = "ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host= "+ip+" user="+usr+" pass= "+pw+"  vm= "+vmName+"\"";`

Comment: The phrase "didn't work" should be banned.

Comment: If you only want a single set of double-quotes around all the extra-vars, why do you have so many escaped double-quotes? If the extra-var values are not supposed to be single-quoted, why do you have all those single quotes? And what is up with all the extra spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by taking the string.

`ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars "host=5.955.595 user=root pass=anotherpw vm=myVm"`

Then you escape all special characters. In this case, that's just the 2 double-quotes.

`ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host=5.955.595 user=root pass=anotherpw vm=myVm\"`

Then you surround that with double-quotes, to make it a Java string literal.

```
"ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host=5.955.595 user=root pass=anotherpw vm=myVm\""
```

Then you remove hardcoded values and replace them with string concatenations with the variables having the dynamic values.

```
"ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host=" + ip + " user=" + usr + " pass=" + pw + " vm=" + vmName + "\""
```

Then you assign it to a variable.

```
String p = "ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host=" + ip + " user=" + usr + " pass=" + pw + " vm=" + vmName + "\"";
```

Then you wrap it over multiple lines, to make it more readable.

```
String p = "ansible-playbook delete.yml --extra-vars \"host=" + ip +
                                                     " user=" + usr +
                                                     " pass=" + pw +
                                                       " vm=" + vmName + "\"";
```

See how easy it is, if you just take it one step at a time?

Comment: Wow... thank you so much. I definitely should have taken it one step at a time :)